# Process running php.ini Using Up Excessive Memory In CentOS

Tags: php, memory-management, centos6

Bear with me here.

I'm seeing some php.ini processes (?) running or processes touching php.ini that are using up to 80% or more of the CPU and i have no idea what would cause this. All database processing is offloaded on a separate VPS and the whole service is supported by a CDN. I've provided a screenshot of "top -cM"

**Setup:**

- MediaTemple DV level 2 application server (the server we are looking at in the images), 8 cores, 2GB RAM
- Mediatemple VE level 1 database server
- Cloudflare CDN
- CentOS 6.5
- NginX
- Mysql 5.4, ect

**EDIT**

I'm seeing about 120K pageviews a day here, with a substantial number of concurrent connections

Where do i start looking to find what is causing this?

Thanks in advance

[image: Screenshot-1]
[image: Screenshot-2]

Comment: they're "php-cgi" processes, which happen to have php.ini as a command line argument. And you can use `ls -l /proc/PID/fd`, where PID is the pid of the process, e.g. 25435, to see what files are in use by that process.

Comment: @MarcB I'm seeing references to the apache error log when running that command on a high-use process:

"/var/log/httpd/error_log"

When opening the error log, i see this entry from yesterday:

"mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper"

Researching tells me that this means i'm hitting the FcgidMaxProcesses limit, which is currently set at 20 in /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf 

Another common entry in the error log is "mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds". Any ideas?